# Why DocumentApp.getUi().alert('blah') can alert in the frontend?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

Such as,addToUi() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addToUi()
or other action like showslidebar. For example, when I excute google.script.run.alert() in the webside

```
# GAS
function alert() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('blahblah');
}
```

The user interface will alert. The function is running in GAS(server-side), how does it can effect the user interface? And there is no websocket.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "how GAS affects the user"? UI block or which kind of alert shows up?

Comment: such as this code which is running in GAS
```
function alert() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().alert('hello world');
}
```
And in the frontend, user can click the menu to show the alert dialog.But actually the request will excute the func in the server-side. How the fronted know that to dialog "hello world". There is no response about that.

Answer (score -1):

### When using Google Workspace Services you are using SaaS

Meaning that Document App has a frontend which you can't directly access to it but through Google Apps Script with certain limitations, e.g: [getUi()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getui) returns an instance of the document's user-interface environment that allows the script to add features like menus, dialogs, and sidebars. In other words you are accessing to its frontend (with limited usage).

Google Apps Script runs on the server side. However, in using the method described above you are able to access the UI and therefore use an **alert**.

### Reference

[Google Apps script > Base > UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)